# Google oauth2Client.getToken is not returning id_token for other users

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-identity

I'm implementing Google's 'code model' of Oauth2 and having trouble getting users' email - I wonder if this is a scopes problem or my misunderstanding about how to set up the code model. This sequence of events is already working:

1. Client loads https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client
2. Client starts call to `google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient`
3. Client gets code
4. Client passes code to one of my server endpoints
5. Server has an oauth2Client set up using the config with client_id, client_secret, and redirect URL = `'postmessage'`
6. Server exchanges the code from the client for tokens
7. Server does `oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens)` - this contains an access_token, which is enough for the client to make API calls to, e.g., retrieve the user's Google Calendar
8. Server is able to do `oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(tokens.access_token);`

There are various places along the way that involve scopes; I am probably getting something confused here. The client's initial call (step 2 above) uses

```
scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
```

My code path on the server does define scopes anywhere.
In GCP, my project is set up with scopes

- calendar.calendarlist.readonly, calendar.readonly and calendar.events.readonly
- openid
- /auth/userinfo.email

Here's the problem I'm encountering: when I go through this flow as a user and oauth with the account that owns the GCP project (this is a Google Workspace email, in case that matters), the tokens object that the server receives (step 6 above) has `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `id_token` - the id_token can be decoded to yield the user's email, and the user's email is also in the response to `oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(token.access_token)`.

However, when I go through the flow with my other (personal) Gmail account, the tokens object that the server receives is missing the `id_token` but has the access and refresh tokens. Question 1: why are the responses different?

Question 2: How can I get the email of the user *on the server* in the personal Gmail account case? I've tried having the server make a call to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?fields=id,email,name,picture` with the access_token, but this fails. I am not sure if I'm supposed to declare scopes for `oauth2Client` somehow, or tap a Google API using a different method on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've had a breakthrough: in step 2 in my original post, when I did "Client starts call to google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient", I had set the scope of `initCodeClient` to just the calendar scope. When I changed it instead to `scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid',` (scope takes a space-delimited list in this case), it allowed my server call to get the id_token for this user and `oauth2Client.getTokenInfo` to get a response with the user's email in it.

When I updated the scopes like that, the popup asking for authorization also updated to request all the scopes I wanted - previously, it was only asking for the Calendar scope, so it makes sense Google didn't want to return the email.

What I still don't understand is why my previous setup was working for the account that owns the GCP project. In other words, when I was first building it out with that owner account, the client was only noting the Calendar scope while the server was asking for all three scopes (ie there was a mismatch), and the server was still able to get an id_token and the user's email in `getTokenInfo`. Maybe the owner account has some special privilege?